# How to enable the parameter hints for C/C++ when difining a function after declaration in VS2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, code-hinting

I just met a question. I declared a function but not defined it yet, then when I decided to define the function, I can't get any parameter hints related to the declaration before, as the picture shows. How to fix this？[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NVUl.png)

Could you please help?

I have enabled the inline hints, but it solves another problem, not mine.